# Large git push fails

Tags: git, push, commit

I have a large commit I am trying to push to the remote. but it keeps failing. It counts and compresses the items fine. But when it tries to write to the remote, it takes a long time. It gets to about 79% and then I get an error.

Something to the effect of: `Remote suddenly hung up on other end`

I've tried breaking the commit up into smaller chunks, but the push still tries to push them altogether. So it's still the same problem. Is there a way to push smaller chunks individually?

Answer (score 4):

If you have split the original commit into smaller commits, you could push them individually using `git push origin abc123:master` (where `abc123` is a commit hash).

(Have you checked that the server isn't out of disk space?)

Comment: Ah... thanks, that makes sense. I should be able to get the commit hash from "git log", yes?

Comment: @belotte: Correct. You can also "undo" the last commit, but still keep the file changes, by doing `git reset HEAD~1`. You might want to do `git branch backupBranch` first so that you still have the original commit.

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned: git push origin a03c048ce8497adda985921a979b4d1d8d74d01:master, and get this: ! [rejected]        8a03c048ce8497adda985921a979b4d1d8d74d01 -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://belotte@bitbucket.org/belotte/my-new-site.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: So then I tried: git pull and got: There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream master origin/<branch>

Comment: So then I tried pull origin master and got:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date. So I'm not sure what to do.